Integration of Vouch Proxy and Next Auth in a PWA: Token forwarding and validation
I have the following structure:
I have a PWA that has a frontend and backend. No authentication is currently performed in the frontend. In front of the frontend is an NGNIX in combination with a vouch proxy. The vouch proxy is the sign that the frontend can only be accessed with authentication. The token is forwarded to the backend by the vouch proxy in order to check it in the backend before each query.
For migration reasons, I would now like to add another Next.JS with Next Auth. For the time being, authentication should continue to take place via the Vouch. Therefore, the Vouch should continue to be used for authentication and then forward the token to NextJS.
But now the question is how to turn this token into a valid login with Next Auth? A new login via the provider (Auth0) should not take place.
In the end, I want the NextAuth login to be automatic, as a login from the vouch already exists.
